# Save winners in Jquery Bracket Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, brackets

I am using Jquery Bracket Plugin for Tournament brackets for my angular2 application.

I have used the following link and is working fine,

http://www.aropupu.fi/bracket/

I need to store the winners in an array and send to backend to save the data. How can I do it?

I have tried the following solution but not working.

https://github.com/teijo/jquery-bracket/pull/47/files

Please help.....

Regards,
Rekha